# Make a Discord Bot show "Bot is typing..." in Discord Chat (DISCORD.JS)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, chatbot

I am relatively new to making Discord bots and I have seen other bots do this but I want to know how you can make the "bot is typing..." effect at the bottom of the chat screen with Discord.JS .

There is a similar question here on Stack Overflow but that is in Discord.py and I need Discord.JS.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this accessing `message.channel.startTyping(count?: number)`

reference: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=startTyping

Comment: As of Jun'23, this is not valid. Please use `await message.channel.sendTyping();`